# asp.net Substring from specific string to the end of the word

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, substring, hashtag

I have a multiline textbox that user may type whatever he wants to  for example,

"Hello my name is #Konstantinos and i am 20 #years old"

Now i want to place a button when is pressed the output will be #Konstantinos and #years -

Is that something that can be done using substring or any other idea?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, that can be done using substring at some point. Why don't you try ?

Comment: why don't you simply ask for name and year separately in different textboxes? parsing a string for name and year would be nothing but a broken code

Comment: As i know substring needs starting index & length but in my case those 2 things are unknown from the very beginning because a user can type his hashtag+word (for example #test) anywhere in his text - so i can't figure out how i can work with substring and asked for your help. Best Regards

Comment: so all that you want is words beginning with hashtags(#) from the entire string ?

Comment: Thats right all i want from the text as output is the words starting with a hash tag - Best Regars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all that you want is `HashTags(#)` from the entire string, you can perform simple `.Split()` and Linq. Try this:

**C#**

```
string a = "Hello my name is #Konstantinos and i am 20 #years old";
var data = a.Split(' ').Where(s => s.StartsWith("#")).ToList();
```

**VB**

```
Dim a As String = "Hello my name is #Konstantinos and i am 20 #years old" 
Dim data = a.Split(" ").Where(Function(s) s.StartsWith("#")).ToList()
```

Comment: +1 VB.net code is : `Dim a As String = "Hello my name is #Konstantinos and i am 20 #years old"
    Dim data = a.Split(" ").Where(Function(s) s.StartsWith("#")).ToList()`

Comment: Seems interesting im trying that and i will let you know - Best Regards

Comment: @Daniel Cook - Thank you too!

Answer (score 1):

Using `regex` will give you more flexibility.

You can define a pattern to search for strings starting with #.

.Net regex [cheat sheet](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet)

```
Dim searchPattern = "#(\S+)" '\S - Matches any nonwhite space character
Dim searchString = "Hello my name is #Konstantinos and i am 20 #years old"

For Each match As Match In Regex.Matches(searchString, searchPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value)
Next
Console.Read()
```

Comment: +1, also works. Just make sure to have `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions` at the top of your code.

Answer (score 0):

This will work . Try this..

```
string str = "Hello my name is #Konstantinos and i am 20 #years old asldkfjklsd #kumod";
        int i=0;
        int k = 0;
        while ((i = str.IndexOf('#', i)) != -1)
        {

            string strOutput = str.Substring(i);
            k = strOutput.IndexOf(' ');
            if (k != -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(strOutput.Substring(0, k));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(strOutput);
            }
            i++;
        }
```